# Is there a MySQL privilege for viewing all client connections without having access to all databases?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL 5.7 with workbench on windows VM. I have a multi-tenant database structure so I want to have a mysql user who does not have access to view all databases but can view all client connections information (the "Client Connections" tab in workbench or `show processlist` for all connections) for DBA monitoring purposes.

I  tried searching for how to enable the client connections tab but could not find answers for this specifically. The PROCESS privilege works for enabling `show processlist` but still does not give access to workbench's client connections tab. Ideally I would like to be able to access the tab as it has helpful computed stats not found in `show processlist`.

Comment: PROCESS privilege? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-processlist.html

Comment: You're asking a question that is a requirement, but not showing us what you tried or where you researched this. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and all their linked pages.

Comment: Thanks @SlawomirDziuba, the PROCESS privilege works for `show processlist`. I had previously only searched for how to enable client connections. However, the PROCESS privilege still does not give the user access to client connections tab in workbench and it gives message "The account you are currently using does not have sufficient privileges to view client connections". I'm having a hard time figuring out which privilege is required for that.

Comment: @theTinMan sorry for that, edited to add more detail

Comment: @aks94  I don't use a workbench. If these statistics are generated by the server, then check the list of server processes which request the workbench sends. This should help you find the permissions you need.

Comment: @SlawomirDziuba Okay, I'm not sure how to find out the server processes for that request. Will keep looking. Thanks again

Comment: @aks94 Enable query logging: SET GLOBAL log_output = 'TABLE';
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';  and then: SELECT * FROM mysql.general_log ORDER BY event_time desc;

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still looking for the answer to this, it is:

`GRANT SELECT ON performance_schema.* TO <username>@<host>`